# Three figures positioned horizontally and vertically

Tags: positioning, eps

I'm trying to get the following layout for three figures in LaTeX
[image]

However, thus far I'm not really getting anywhere. What I've found is a way to put them next to each other, but they are too large to fit next to each other. I used

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.7in]{something.eps}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~
        \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.7in]{something.eps}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.7in]{something.eps}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{label}
\end{figure}
```

But this simply positions them horizontally. Could anyone help me figure out how to put the figures in the above layout?

Comment: What is your preambule ? Please give a complete MWE.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't fully think the post through I suppose. My question is how I can achieve such a layout in LaTeX, as I haven't succeeded myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.7in]{figure-1}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    &
        \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.7in]{figure-1}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \\
    % uncomment next line
    % \multicolumn{x}{c}{%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.7in]{figure-1}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%}// <- uncomment
    % comment next line
    & \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm having some issues with aligning the a,b,c under the figures, but I'm not sure that's something that can be done independently of the figure itself. Apart from that it's great! If only I had 4 figures instead of 3 though..

Comment: on the second line try `\multicolumn{c}{2}{your image} \\\` instead off `your image& \\\`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow completely. At which line should I add that?

Comment: @user129412 See my edit.

Comment: I feel rather stupid, but it says gives the error ! Missing number, treated as zero.